# /testfor and /tp Commands

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is there a certain command that recognizes a dropped item on a pressure plate, and then teleports the player who dropped it? I have an item I want them to craft and drop onto the pressure plate.

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Comment: I have I have been attempting this for almost 4 hours straight

Comment: You haven't actually included any of that in your question, however.  If you've been working on this, show us what you've tried!  That will help a lot.

Comment: @Cole http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Screenshot At least search something up before you comment, OK? It's the first thing that popped up.

Comment: I meant to send it over to here

Comment: I already have screen shots XD

Comment: @Cole Can you include them within the question so we can see them?

Answer (score 0):

use execute command. (haven't tested commands)

```
/execute @e[type=item] ~ ~ ~ testforblock ~ ~ ~ stone_pressureplate
```

have a comparator going from command block to another (as i said, didn't test command)

```
/tp @p[r=3] x,y,z
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in one command in Minecraft 1.13

```
/execute at @e[type=item] if block ~ ~ ~ stone_pressureplate run tp @p[distance=..3] X Y Z
```